# Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar not working after migrating to androidx

Tags: android

I was using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar on my activities which worked flawlessly but I had to migrate to Androidx to use a library and after migrating there's now an actionBar.

I tried googling but could not get any fixes

Here's my code

Style.xml

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: Still have this issue `resource android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar not found`... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I just cleaned and rebuilt the project

Answer (score 4):

Always after Migrating to AndroidX it's better to do: **File Menu** > **Invalidate Caches / Restart**

Comment: If It not works. try to delete the gradle cache by `rm -rf /Users/user/.gradle/caches`